# Unable to align bottom feature for included layout in other xml

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I have a footer xml file. I am including that file in all other files like....

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/footer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

     <include layout="@layout/footer" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

But I am getting warning like "Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_alignParentBottom"
         can any one tell me how to align the included xml at bottom without using sizes

Comment: Change your top most layout to RelativeLayout and then you would be able to set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use property `alignParentBottom` in LinearLayout. That's for RelativeLayout.

For LinearLayout, you can use `layout_gravity`

```
<LinearLayout> <!-- container LinearLayout -->
    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/footer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom">

         <include layout="@layout/footer" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While using layout_gravity the tab bar images are not displaying. I have a tab bar with image and text

Comment: That means you have problem in your layout structure. Show full xml.

Answer (score 0):

This code will bring your stuff to the bottom(Footer).

This will be your Footer XML.

footer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/footer_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"> 
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Now Include your footer xml in the layouts you want to.

such as,

abc.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/abc_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/footer"
         android:id="@+id/footer_test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope This Helps :)